# Возможно ли добавить кнопку в Indesign для того, чтобы помечать как "избранное" ("добавить в избранное", "Добавить в корзину" как на сайте магазинов)

Tags: pdf

**Есть задача:** разработать интерактивный PDF-файл с продукцией в виде карточки продукции (например, https://www.ozon.ru/category/literatura-dlya-podrostkov-33015/).
**Вопрос:** возможно ли реализовать в Indesign (в PDF) кнопку, которая будет аналогична кнопке "добавить в корзину", "отметить", "добавить в избранное" на сайтах интернет-магазинах?

Comment: Уточните, что вы вкладываете в понятие *"аналогична кнопке ... на сайтах интернет-магазинах"*? Опишите сценарий предполагаемой работы.

Comment: @Kromster Здравствуйте! В файле PDF, в каталоге товаров (книг) на изображении товара будет кнопка в виде звездочки, при нажатии на неё (звездочку) товар будет помещен в отдельное окно или список, или страницу с помеченными звездочкой товаром. А уже с этого отдельного окна, списка, страницы будет оформляться заказ, но это уже другая история

Comment: Из того что я помню, PDF это просто документ (типа DOCX). На чем будет реализовано ваше *"отдельное окно, список, или страница"*?

Comment: @Kromster Пытался реализовать отдельной страницей с ссылкой на него, но не получается. Если это не реализуемо, то каким способом я могу это реализовать? С помощью каких программ?

Comment: Это большая задача, с наскока не решается. Ищите друга программиста или аналитика и садитесь обсуждать от бизнес-потребности.

Comment: @Kromster Спасибо за совет!